# Drupal From Network File Share

Tags: installation

We are working on a primary/secondary server configuration for a Drupal 8 install. I have been asked to look at the option of running the Drupal install from a file share so the same instance of Drupal can be shared across both servers. I have concerns about doing this, and I am looking for input from anyone who has tried this configuration. First, I'm just wondering if this is considered a best practice. More importantly, I would like feedback on performance, technical issues and any surprises you may have encountered.

Comment: This isn't really answerable to be honest - there's going to be a marked difference depending on your network and environment. Running this on an un-contested 10gbps connection will get you better results than running it on a congested 100mbps connection, for example. There's no way to extrapolate an average, because network conditions are ephemeral. You should identify a way to come up with a benchmark that your happy with, based on speed/uptime requirements etc, and then benchmark your site in the intended environment

Comment: That is the current plan. I guess I am constitutionally opposed to this idea for a few reasons, and was wondering if there was any experience out there that would provide information that could change either my mind or the manager's. I am not finding any information on this setup anywhere, so it seems like we would be an outlier, which means unexpected problems and little community support. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I’ve tried it before and failed miserably, but it was a while ago now. It does exist (Acquia and Pantheon both do it at scale), but when it goes wrong, oh wow is it spectacular

Answer (score 2):

I used to help support a major medical health organisation's website. The sysadmin there had the site running on 3 separate machines across two datacenters.  It was D7 but should work with D8.

The setup was that there were 2 'production' machines and 1 edit machine. The edit machine was only accessible from inside the firewall.  The production machines were behind separate varnish cache servers, tied together via a load balancer.  All admin commands were blocked for this in the apache config so the Production boxes were basically read only.

They were connected by a MySQL clustered database with each machine having a MySQL node.  The code base was local and pulled in via git.

I think they tried to use NSF to share the user files but had some issues (may have been due to firewall issues between the different sites).  So I think he was actually using a permanent rsync script running to copy files uploaded on the edit machine to the production machines.

It was nice for code rollouts.  He would duplicate the production database and set the edit machine to use the duplicate.  We would pull in the new code, sync settings via features, and run QA on it.  Once it passed, he would take one server out of production, change it to use the new DB, code from Git, and sync files with the edit server.

The load balancer was swapped to use the new code (new code/features available in < 2s).  Then update the other server offline.

He had a lot of different custom scripts to manage this so it was not that bad.

Also, although he didn't use it for production, he was using Aegir to manage the development environment we had.  Basically, senior devs could use it to do code pulls and push stuff to the dev QA boxes.

YMMV